# Regex pattern for matching float followed by some fixed strings

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to a regex pattern that could match the following cases:

`0, 1, 0.1, .1, 1g, 0.1g, .1g, 1(g/100ml), .1(g/ml)`

If the regex matches the pattern, I want to capture only the numerical part(`0,1,0.1..`)

I tried using following regex but it matches many cases:

```
((?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))|((?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))[a-zA-Z]+?|\([^)]*\)
```

How to achieve above with single regex pattern?

Edit:

To make the question solution more generic
What would be a single regex that would match below

1. Any numerical ( 0, 1, 0.1, ...)
2. Any numerical followed by g, mg any characters (0.1g, .1mg, 100kg)
3. Any numerical followed by anything in parentheses -  .1(g/100ml), 100(mg/1kg)

And just capture the numerical part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** With OP's edited samples(to match `0, 1, 0.1`  OR `(0.1g, .1mg, 100kg)` OR `.1(g/100ml), 100(mg/1kg)`), adding following solution here. Explanation is same as very first solution, only thing is in spite of matching specific strings, I have changed regex to match any alphabets here.

```
(\d*\.?\d+)(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\([a-zA-Z]+(?:\/\d*(?:[a-zA-Z]+))?\)|(?:,\s+|$))
```

[Online Demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/kbqntV/1)

---

---

***EDIT1:*** As per OP's comments to match .01c and 100(g/1000L) kind of examples adding following regex, which is small edit to 1st solution here.

```
(\d*\.?\d+)(?:g|cc|\(g(?:\/\d*(?:ml|L))?\)|(?:,\s+|$))
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/smSkKB/1)

---

---

With your shown samples, please try following regex here.

```
(\d*\.?\d+)(?:g|\(g(?:\/\d*ml)?\)|(?:,\s+|$))
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/AkBBFf/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(\d*\.?\d+)           ##Matching digits 0 or more occurrences followed by .(optional, followed by 1 or more digits occurrences here.
(?:                   ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
  g|                  ##matching only g here OR.
  \(g(?:\/\d*ml)?\)|  ##Matching (g) OR (g/digits ml) here OR.
  (?:,\s+|$)          ##Matching comma followed by 1 or more spaces occurrences OR end of value here.
)                     ##Closing non-capturing group here.
```

Comment: It won't match `.1`

Comment: @anubhava, Thanks sir, changing it to `(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)(?:g|\(g(?:\/\d*ml)?\)?|(?:,\s|$))` once. Please do let me know if this looks ok to you.

Comment: I has to be `\d*\.?\d+` otherwise it will match an empty string

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you for letting know, I have edited regex with mentioned one now.

Answer (score 4):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific and use a capture group for the digits and optionally match what follows or (Updated with the comment of [@ anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)) add a word boundary to prevent another partial match.

```
(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\(g\/\d*ml\)|g?\b)
```

- `(\d*\.?\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match optional digits, optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `\(g\/\d*ml\)` Match `(g/` optional digits and `ml)`
  - `|` Or
  - `g?\b` Match an optional `g` followed by a word boundary
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aFKQk0/1)

If the values should match in the comma separated string, you can assert either a `,` or the end of the string to the right.

```
(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\(g\/\d*ml\)|g)?(?=,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxxVp8/1)

**Edit**

A broad pattern to match anything between parenthesis or optional chars a-zA-Z after the digits:

```
(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\([^()]*\)|[a-zA-Z]*\b)
```

- `(\d*\.?\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match optional digits, optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\([^()]*\)` Match from opening till closing parenthesis
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-zA-Z]*\b` Optionally match chars in the ranges a-zA-Z followed by a word boundary
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sXZ0AE/1)

Comment: ++ but do we really need `(?!\S)` ?

Comment: @anubhava If I omit the `(?!\S)` the part after the digits is optional and `\d*\.?\d+` will also match the digits in the example. So I thought to give it a boundary preventing it from matches any digit anywhere.

Comment: I came up with `(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\(g\/\d*ml\)|g|\b)`

Comment: @anubhava Cool, then the word boundary is in the alternation. That's smart :-) you should post it.

Comment: No it is just a small tweak in your solution

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for the regex.. How to tweak the above to suit say the below case: Any numerical or Any numerical followed by g,mg any characters or Any numerical followed by anything in parentheses..  0.1, 1, 0.1cc, 100(g/1000L) etc... But just capture the numerical part..

Comment: @user1529282 The broad variant of the pattern is `(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\([^()]*\)|[a-zA-Z]*\b)` https://regex101.com/r/JZblNz/1

Comment: @user1529282: please update requirement in question itself with examples.

Comment: If the input is ".1(g/10ml", in the above case we would have 2 matches… Can the regex be made exclusive?

Comment: @user1529282 Yes you can exclude matching the closing parenthesis `(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\([^()\n]*|[a-zA-Z]*\b)` https://regex101.com/r/sstEG8/1 Or not match parenthesis or a whitespace char `(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\([^()\s]*|[a-zA-Z]*\b)` https://regex101.com/r/5UAJ2u/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Sorry, I meant for the examples in https://regex101.com/r/lcX2qm/3, I do not want them to be matched at all... Can that be possible?

Comment: @user1529282 That was actually in my first approach using whitespace boundaries `(?<!\S)(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\([^()]*\)|[a-zA-Z]*)(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/5zklJV/1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[\d]?\.?\d+(?:g|(?<p>\()(?(p)g\/(?:\d+)?ml\)))?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8X05UB/1)